# lotus notes section from bash text file

Tags: bash, lotus-notes, mailx

I would like to be able to send a mail from unix/bash using mailx and cat(

example:

```
cat testMailWithSection.txt | mailx -s "testMail" -r "sender@machine" "destination@company" &
```

however, it would be a long mail, and I'd like to put parts of it in a section. Is this possible with just these tools?

Greetings

Comment: can you include the contents of testMailWithSection.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no.  In fact it isn't that easy to create sections programmatically on code either, but that would be the only way. There's no way to convert markup from an email body into sections on the Notes client.